# Jodas LocalDateTime with Spring Data and Couchbase has no timezone

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, couchbase

I wanna persistant an object with LocalDateTime fields with spring data and a couchbase behind in a spring boot app.

Here are the fieldmapping:

```
@Field
private LocalDateTime start;

@Field
private LocalDateTime end;
```

When I save the object then the dates are stored as numbers in couchbase.

Here are the stored data in couchbase:

```
"start": 1518818215508,
```

So the problem is, if I store an LocalDateTime e.g at 10.00, and then read it from db the result is 09:00 instead of 10:00 because of my local time +1:00.

In Postgres I would save the date in an column with mapping: columnDefinition= "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE"

How I can solve this problem in couchbase?

Answer (score 3):

JSON (famously) has no date format (unlike relational databases which have a sprawling number of different formats). If you want to store timezone data in JSON, here are two options I can think of:

- Using a string instead of a number, and then using something like [ISO-8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html).
- Store the epoch time as you currently are as a UTC value, but also store a separate number field that represents a timezone offset from UTC

I would recommend going with the first approach.

I'm no Spring/Java expert, but a quick look at the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/) says you can do this by setting system property `org.springframework.data.couchbase.useISOStringConverterForDate` to true